# Plugin container in NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to create a modular web api in .NET Core MVC Api. I made this before in the classic .NET, but I used MEF for that. All my plugin containers are in different NuGet packages and I restore them accordingly.
However, in the new version, NuGet packages are stored in a general folder and not in the solution. For my script to find the plugins (by interface) I need to load the in my assembly, but I cannot find them since the DLLs of the NuGet packages are not in the solution anymore.

Can I set the restore directory of NuGet to my solution? Or is there an other way to fix this.

Thanks

**----Update----**

Thanks to UserName is came up with this solution:

Edit the CSPROJ file of the MVC API and change this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="NeedsToBeLocal" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" ExcludeAssets="Runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" ExcludeAssets="Runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="NeedsToBeLocal" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(mind the ExcludeAssets="Runtime").

Next, add the following Property group:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Last, add these targets to the CSPROJ:

```
<Target Name="CopyAdditionalFilesToLayout" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == ''" DependsOnTargets="PrepareAdditionalFilesToLayout" AfterTargets="Build" Inputs="@(LayoutFile)" Outputs="@(LayoutFile-&gt;'$(PackageLayoutOutputPath)%(TargetPath)')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(LayoutFile)" DestinationFiles="@(LayoutFile-&gt;'$(PackageLayoutOutputPath)%(TargetPath)')">
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites" />
    </Copy>
</Target>  

<Target Name="FilterCopyLocal" DependsOnTargets="GetFrameworkPaths;GetReferenceAssemblyPaths;RunResolvePublishAssemblies" BeforeTargets="ResolveLockFileCopyLocalProjectDeps">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CopyLocalButNotPublished Include="@(AllCopyLocalItems)" Exclude="@(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish)" />
      <AllCopyLocalItems Remove="@(_CopyLocalButNotPublished)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Clean & Rebuild and the correct libraries will be copied to the debug folder (netcoreapp2.0 in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible ways is using [RestorePackagesPath](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild#project-properties) property in projects:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RestorePackagesPath>..\packages</RestorePackagesPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

From [documentation](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/[Spec]-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild):

> RestorePackagesPath - Path to the user packages folder. All downloaded
>   packages are extracted here. Equivalent to --packages in dotnet
>   restore.

---

You can use `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` property. If it set as `true`, then dependencies will copied to output folder from NuGet cache.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: That will store the packages to a different folder, yes. But I only want the DLL's placed in the bin/debug or bin/release. Just like it has always been. I have no use for the nupkg-files and stuff.
When I install a package and build the solution, the referenced DLL's are NOT in the bin/$(Configuration)/$(TargetFramework)

Comment: works! Thanks. One final question; is it also possible to copy only certain DLLs from NuGet packages to the build folder?

Comment: @JohanFrijhof, I don't tried, but I found [it](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks.csproj#L96). I check this later and by results will I extend answer.

Comment: Yes! That is it. Was a bit of a puzzle, but I figured it out. See my update